# Validation In Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I am learning Xamarin Forms and am attempting to add in validation.  What I want to do is if a valid email address is not input, then I want to outline the field in red and display a hidden label.

I get this error:

> System.NullReferenceException has been thrown

In my my XF_Login.iOS

This is my syntax:

```
    <ContentPage.Content>  
    <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" Padding="30" Spacing="40">  
        <BoxView HeightRequest="10"/>  
        <Frame BackgroundColor="#BF043055" HasShadow="False">  
            <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" Spacing="10"> 
                <Entry x:Name="Email" Text="{Binding Email}" Placeholder="Email"   
                       PlaceholderColor="Red" HeightRequest="50" 
                       TextColor="Black"/>
                <Label x:Name="emailerror"  Text="Error this is invalid format.  Please udpate" TextColor="Red" /> 
            </StackLayout>  
        </Frame>  
        <Button Command="{Binding SubmitCommand}" Text="Register" TextColor="White"  
                FontAttributes="Bold" FontSize="Large" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"  
                BackgroundColor="#088da5" Clicked="OnRegisterTap" />  
    </StackLayout>  
</ContentPage.Content> 

//Constructor
public RegisterPage()
{
        //Setting the label to invisible until needed
        emailerror.IsVisible = false;

        //Wiring up the event for the email check
        Email.Completed += new EventHandler(Email_Completed);

        InitializeComponent();
}

//Custom event
void Email_Completed(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        bool isEmail = Regex.IsMatch(Email.Text, @"\A(?:[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?)\Z", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

        if (isEmail == false)
        {
            emailerror.IsVisible = true;
            Email.BackgroundColor = Color.FromHex("#2c3e50");
            Email.TextColor = Color.Red;
        }
 }
    void OnRegisterTap(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       App.Current.MainPage = new NavigationPage(new AlreadyRegistered());
}
public partial class AlreadyRegistered : ContentPage
{
    public AlreadyRegistered()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
 //Error Method
 namespace XF_Login.iOS
{
public class Application
{
    // This is the main entry point of the application.
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // if you want to use a different Application Delegate class from "AppDelegate"
        // you can specify it here.
        UIApplication.Main(args, null, "AppDelegate");
    }
}
}
```

Comment: which line causes the exception?  And where is the call to InitializeComponent in your constructor?  Did you accidentally delete it?

Comment: @Jason - sorry that was a copy/paste error.  This is the line of code that causes the error.  On my button press event -            `App.Current.MainPage = new NavigationPage(new AlreadyRegistered());`

Comment: what does the constructor of AlreadyRegistered look like?  So far this appears to have nothing to do with your validation

Comment: @Jason - I'll edit my OP to include the constructor for AlreadyRegistered.  That's interesting as if I comment out the Email_Completed method as well as the Email_Completed in my constructor the code executes fine

Comment: does this only happen when you click Register and the email field is empty?

Comment: This happens on the Page Load for the register page.  The "start screen" is a login page with a login button and a register button at the bottom.  If the user presser's the register button it should load this page, but instead it throws the error

Comment: there are two potenital issues I see; 1) Email.Completed +=  Email_Completed; (should not need the new EventHandler()), and 2) Email.Text could be null when you execute the Regex, which could cause an exception.  You should test for null first

Comment: Well it's throwing the error on page load, how would you advise I test for null?

Comment: String.IsNullOrEmpty(Email.Text)

Comment: ah, and be sure InitializeComponent runs FIRST

Comment: Should InitializeComponent run before the EventHandler I am setting up?

Comment: yes, it should be the FIRST thing in your constructor.  It is responsible for loading the XAML.  If you do not call it first the XAML references are probably null

Comment: @Jason - that remedied my initial error, but the method I set-up for validation on email is never called?  And I tried to wire up the event using both new EventHandler() and w/o it.

Comment: How are you testing?  The Completed event only fires when the user hits Return

Comment: I'm tabbing to the next field, or the user could tap/click into the next field.  Should I use a diff event other than Completed?

Comment: why not have the colors in an XAML file instead of behind code?

Comment: @NevilleNazerane - I am completely new to all of this.  How would you recommend using a XAML file?

Comment: in your ` <Label x:Name="emailerror"` you can make it ` <Label x:Name="emailerror" TextColor="Red"`. Basically as much as possible, you can have your UI inside your XAML. since it is easier to manage UI on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, in a XAML code behind you must call `InitializeComponent` in the constructor before you reference any XAML elements.  `InitializeComponent` handles loading the XAML elements, if you do not call it the refs will be null.

Second, `Completed` only fires when Return is pressed on an `Entry` field.  To detect when a user moves to another field, try using `Unfocused` instead.

Comment: if I change my syntax to Email.Unfocus += Email_Unfocus; I get a compile error of can not assign to Email.Unfocus bc it is a method group

Comment: Should be Unfocused

Comment: That got it!!  Sorry for my beginner mistakes